# Show table on radio button select, then pass radio button value to field in table, option to add more, then append to existing table

Tags: javascript

First-time poster...please don't beat me up too bad. I'm not even sure how all of this works, but here goes. I'm basically trying to recreate the form located here: http://yeticustomshop.com/get-quote
I have the product selection showing and the table showing as of right now.

Needed user experience:

1. Select Product, product selection is replaced by table showing product selection name, checkbox, and quantity selector.
2. Option to add another product. If clicked, show product selection, then the process is repeated, adding new selections to table.
3. The ability to remove previously selected items.

Any takers?

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cuszuz3k/)

```
    // Get all the product radio buttons and loop them
var products = document.getElementsByName('product');
for (var i = products.length; i--;) {
    // add an event listener to do stuff when one of them is clicked
    products[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        // get the value of the clicked button
        var cup = this.value;
        // put the value in the input box
        document.getElementById('yourSelection').value = cup;
        // hide the radio buttons and show the table
        document.getElementById("cupDesc").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("cupSelect").style.display = "none";
    });
}
```

Thanks to user "[I wrestled a bear once](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1444609/i-wrestled-a-bear-once)" for the help!

Comment: bruh. there are code formatters available over the place.

Comment: please include your javascript so far.

Comment: I've tried different ones, but that was before I changed the #cupDesc div into a table. I'll add what I've tried to the original post.

Comment: bruh. formatters as far as the eye can see. i use [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to tidy stuff up for SO sometimes. also, please hit the "edit" button to add to the question as opposed to posting code in the comments.

Comment: Apologies...again, first timer and I know pretty much nothing about javascript. I'm attempting to create a fiddle now.

Comment: I think I created a fiddle...https://jsfiddle.net/tk6a7f55/1/

Comment: I've adjusted the original request to show the fixed issues. Step 1 is complete. Now, when the user clicks ADD ADDITIONAL PRODUCT, the Product Selection (Radio Buttons) should re-appear under the table. If another product is selected, that row needs to be added to the original table. Please see  http://yeticustomshop.com/get-quote for example.

Comment: For future visitors who are googling for similar issues we like to keep different issues in separate questions. please create a new question and if you like you can link back to this one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Please pay attention to the comments for the explanation.

```
// Get all the product radio buttons and loop them
var products = document.getElementsByName('product');
for (var i = products.length; i--;) {
    // add an event listener to do stuff when one of them is clicked
    products[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        // get the value of the clicked button
        var cup = this.value;
        // put the value in the input box
        document.getElementById('yourSelection').value = cup;
        // hide the radio buttons and show the table
        document.getElementById("cupDesc").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("cupSelect").style.display = "none";
    });
}
```

Note that you should hide the selection table until the radio button is clicked with `style='display:none'`

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cuszuz3k/)

Happy coding!