# On click, I need the button to hide and a hidden div to appear

Tags: javascript, forms, simplecart

I'm attempting to recreate the form located here: http://yeticustomshop.com/get-quote (PLEASE look at this for reference)

Needed user experience:

- Select Product, product selection is replaced by table showing
  product selection name, checkbox, and quantity selector.
- Option to add another product. If clicked, button disappears and the
  product selection is shown BELOW the table. Then the process is
  repeated, adding new selections to table.
- The ability to remove previously selected items.

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkcdesign/ur7h2q10/1/)

```
// Get all the product radio buttons and loop them
var products = document.getElementsByName('product');
for (var i = products.length; i--;) {
  // add an event listener to do stuff when one of them is clicked
  products[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    // get the value of the clicked button
    var cup = this.value;
    // put the value in the input box
    document.getElementById('yourSelection').value = cup;
    // hide the radio buttons and show the table
    document.getElementById("cupDesc").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("addProductBtn").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("cupSelect").style.display = "none";
  });
}
```

[Here's my previous post on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515933/show-table-on-radio-button-select-then-pass-radio-button-value-to-field-in-tabl)

Side note: This process is being used in a form. I'm wondering if it would be possible and easier to almost make it like a shopping cart. I've downloaded simplecart.js, but Javascript is NOT my strong-suit. Please help.

Comment: The "yeti" site is using jQuery, and it looks like you are not. davs333 comment about the `toggle()` method is something in jQuery. It is my practice **not** to poke at the `display` style, but instead to add and remove descriptive classes to the elements: `document.getElementById("cupDesc").classList.add("showing")` — you can use `.add('classname')` and `.remove('classname')` on the classList. Then you simply have CSS styles for `.showing` and `.hiding`

Comment: OK, so I've changed up my fiddle a little. When I click "Add Additional Product", nothing is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Most updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hkcdesign/ur7h2q10/12/